# Joomla 4 Login - JAuthentication: :authenticate: Failed to load plugin:

Tags: joomla-4.x

Today I upgraded My Joomla 4.2.9 to 4.3.2. Since then i've not been able to login to the administrator area. When I try to login I see the following error.

> JAuthentication: :authenticate: Failed to load plugin:

The username and password is correct.

I have access to the web host, files and database.

Any ideas how I can fix this or what I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known issue with the 4.3.2 upgrade. If I find a link I'll post.

I had to re-install the Joomla core files again, all is working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Update your configuration.php file to show a more details regarding the error and that should give you some indication of the Plugin that is failing to load.

```
public $error_reporting = 'maximum';
...
public $debug = true;
```

From there you can then browse through the #__extensions table of your Joomla instance and find the Plugins with `Authentication` in the `folder` field and based on your findings from the messages change the `enable` field to zero for the offending Plugin.

If the messages don't provide a clear candidate then disable any 3rd party plugins with `Authentication` in the `folder` field. The `_joomla` and `_cookie` are the only two you probably need to have enabled.

All this will get you able to login, as to how to fix the cause that will come when you find out which plugin is/was failing.